# Plotting NormalDistributions with different means and standard deviations

Tags: plotting, graphics, distributions

I've been using the Mathematica reference code to create normal distributions:

```
Plot[Table[PDF[NormalDistribution[0, \[Sigma]], x], {\[Sigma], {.75, 1, 2}}] //Evaluate, {x, -6, 6}, Filling -> Axis]
```

This gives me a nice chart with three bell curves, each with the same mean but varying standard deviations

Is it possible for me to put multiple bell curves with varying means and SDs in the same chart?
what have I have so far is:

```
Plot[Table[PDF[NormalDistribution[\[Mu], \[Sigma]], x], {\[Sigma], {.75, 1, 2}}, {\[Mu], {1, 2, 3}}] // Evaluate, {x, -6, 6}, Filling -> Axis]
```

This unfortunately creates a total of 9 bell curves, instead of the three I want. The goal is to obtain a graph with three curves that have the traits:
1. Mean = 1; SD = .75
2. Mean = 2; SD = 1
3. Mean = 3; SD = 2

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Try `Plot[MapThread[Function[{μ, σ}, PDF[NormalDistribution[μ, σ], x]], {{1, 2, 3}, {0.75, 1, 2}}] // Evaluate, {x, -6, 6}, Filling -> Axis]`

Comment: Worked! Thank you!!